Splitting field for $x^3+2x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$
I'm fairly inexperienced in abstract algebra, and I'm self studying a textbook and came across some splitting field problems; one of which is find the splitting field of $x^3+2x+2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.
I understand that an extension field $\mathbb{E}$ of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is a splitting field of $p(x) = x^3+2x+2$ if there exists elements $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb{E}$ such that $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{Z}_3(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and $p(x) = (x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_n)$.
How do I go about finding the splitting field of $p(x)$ if $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and thus has no roots? Because I also know in general that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}[x]$, then there exists a splitting field $\mathbb{K}$ of $p(x)$ that is unique up to isomorphism.
Do I construct the field $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle p \rangle$ since $\langle x^3+2x+2\rangle $ is a maximal ideal generated by $p(x)$?
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

The field $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle p\rangle$ has a root of $x^3+2x+2$. Then you need to see whether the other roots are already present in that field, or if you need to adjoin other roots until you get the full splitting field. (If you know more stuff about finite fields you can save yourself some work, but without that knowledge you would need to verify that a single root suffices to split the polynomial).

Let $\varepsilon=\pm1$. Then, $\bmod3$, $(x+\varepsilon)^3+2(x+\varepsilon)+2=x^3+2x+2$.
